# Only one side can not smooth

Tags: modifiers, mirror, subdivision-surface

I used skin, mirror and subdivision modifiers in my blender, but I'm having trouble not being subdivision on only one side.
I want you to help

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem on 2.8, it might be bugged

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOBCW.png) in Blender 2.8 [2019-02-02], it must have happened in a newer release? Which release are you using mckee? Can you upload your Blend file to blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: If that vertex is marked as root try to mark another one instead. Though that looks mostly as unexpected behaviour

Comment: Can reproduce now, Mr Zak's comment is the solution.

Comment: Hello.
Thank you for your comments.
Sorry for the late reply.
This problem, but it was able to solve it by applying a skin modifier after creating a shape by extruding a vertex first!